# xsl adding a dynamic id for a span into a for each

Tags: xslt

Hi im generating html from my xsl and i want to generate a unique id for a tag, this is in order to call a function in js inside the xsl that needs this id...
this is a simplifiyed sample of my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
             <span id="spanDescription"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable and `concat()`:

```
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
    <span id="{$id}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('replaceAll(',$id,');')"/>
    </script>
```

Comment: Will it be random or always the same ID no matter where or how many time refreshed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809765/how-to-append-a-number-to-an-id-inside-an-xsl-file

Comment: I also get this error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: replaceAll is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `generate-id()` function :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
             <span id="{generate-id()}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Kowalski thats just what i need but unfortunately i dont know how to do to pass this generated id to the javascript function.... this is the code: <span id="spanDescription"/><script type="text/javascript">replaceAll('<xsl:value-of select="substring(Descripcion,1,90)"/>');
  </script>

Comment: No problem ;) I think that you should edit your original question and describe your problem a little bit more. I don't understand if you're generating the javascript with XSLT or something else.