# How to append a number to an ID inside an XSL file

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

I have the following XSL file which will be repeated many times (in my case 4 times):

```
<xsl:if test="Html/root/lcGroup/txtCity != ''">
    <div id="labOCSign" class="tableHeading"></div>
    <h4>
        <span id="spnCity">
            <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/lcGroup/txtCity" />
        </span>
        <xsl:if test="Html/root/lcGroup/txtZip != ''">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/lcGroup/dlState" />
            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/lcGroup/txtZip" />
        </xsl:if>
    </h4>
</xsl:if>
```

CSS:

```
.tableHeading
{
    background: #E5E5E5 url("../theImages/recommendationBadge.png") top left no-repeat;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.tableHeading2
{
    background: #E5E5E5 url("../theImages/recommendationBadge2.png") top left no-repeat;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

I have the following JQuery which will replace class of the `labOCSign`:

```
var cityName = $(".spnCity").text();
var weekDay = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][(new Date()).getDay()];

if (cityName.toLowerCase() == "rye") {
    if (weekDay == "Monday" || weekDay == "Wednesday" || weekDay == "Friday") {
        if (validNow("08:00AM", "5:30PM")) {
            $("#labOCSign").removeClass("tableHeading2").addClass("tableHeading");
        }
        else {
            $("#labOCSign").removeClass("tableHeading").addClass("tableHeading2");
        }
    }
}
else if (cityName.toLowerCase() == "new roc") {
    if (weekDay == "Monday" || weekDay == "Wednesday" || weekDay == "Friday") {
        if (validNow("08:00AM", "5:30PM")) {
            $("#labOCSign").removeClass("tableHeading2").addClass("tableHeading");
        }
        else {
            $("#labOCSign").removeClass("tableHeading").addClass("tableHeading2");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I have now is the script only takes one instance.

How can I add a number after `spanCity` to ensure they are all unique in the XSL file?

So, it will be #spnCity1, #spnCity2, #spnCity3, #spnCity4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the provided XSLT part is e.g. in an `<xsl:for-each>` loop, you can use `position()` to get an incremented value (the current position in the loop) and `concat()`:

```
<span id="concat('spnCity', position())">
```

**Update** as suggested approach didn't work in the settings:

Two different kind of notations that should work are:

```
<span>
  <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('spnCity', position())"/>
</span>
```

and

```
<span>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('spnCity', position())"/> 
  </xsl:attribute>
</span>
```

The content can just be added after the attribute:

```
<span>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('spnCity', position())"/> 
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/lcGroup/txtCity" />
</span>
```

Just created a [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaF3) with both versions.

Comment: Thanks. It won't be a random number right? So it will start from `1` and increment for as many ID?

Comment: @SiKni8 Yes, but as mentioned it depends on where it's applied. If e.g. in a `for-each` loop, it will increment and return the position of the current node in the loop relative to all nodes in the selected node list. For reference e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: When I look at the HTML source, I see this: `<h4><span id="concat('spnCity', position())">Beverly</span>, NY 12360</h4>` and not the ID itself.

Comment: @SiKni8 Just updated my answer with an additional version that should work.